# Why do I get .perldb alias syntax error when trying to display source?

Tags: perl, debugging, alias

I would like to display whole source code of perl script. Following line was added to .perldb:

```
$DB::alias{'code'} = 'l 1+99999;';
```

the .perldb chmod is set to 700. After issuing my alias I get following error:

```
  DB<1> code
Number found where operator expected at (eval 8)[/usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl:2312] line 1, near "l 1"
    (Do you need to predeclare l?)
Couldn't evaluate `code' alias: syntax error at (eval 8)[/usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl:2312] line 1, near "l 1"
```

alias seems to be loaded correctly:

```
  DB<2> =
code    l 1+100;
```

**EDIT**:
When I define alias using '=' command it works as expected:

```
 DB<2> = code l 1+99999
shcd    = l 1+99999

  DB<3> =
code    l 1+99999
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the alias `code` and remove that content with the command you want to run. So inside the `.perldb` do a substitution command to get it, like:

```
$DB::alias{ 'code' } = 's/^.*$/l 1+99999/';
```

And then in the debugger use:

```
DB<100> code
```

And it will output the whole code of the script (if has less lines that one hundred thousand :-)

Comment: Thank you for reply, this worked. Can you please explain what your code is doing? If I understand well it replaces all lines of source code with "l 1+99999" ? Why is this necessary? I was following this tutorial http://affy.blogspot.sk/p5be/ch16.htm#Examples:%20Creating%20Command%20Aliases regarding alias creation and there was no mention of doing this. When I declare aliases temporary (only for one script) using '=' there is no need to do this. Thank you

Comment: I didn't know of that page. As I understand the value is code that has to replace the alias with the instruction to execute. And in this case it will do always that it finds a sentence beginning with `code`. From command-line it works directly, but I don't know why.